# get the description from an WMI class using vbscript

Tags: windows, vbscript, wmi

How can I get the description from an WMI class using vbscript?

I found this example but it's in C#:

```
// Gets the class description.
try
{
    // Gets the property qualifiers.
    ObjectGetOptions op = new ObjectGetOptions(null, System.TimeSpan.MaxValue, true);

    ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass(namespace,
        classname, op);
    mc.Options.UseAmendedQualifiers = true;

    foreach (QualifierData dataObject in
        mc.Qualifiers)
    {
        if(dataObject.Name.Equals("Description"))
        {
            classdesc = 
                dataObject.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
catch (ManagementException mErr)
{
    if(mErr.Message.Equals("Not found "))
        MessageBox.Show("WMI class or not found.");
    else
        MessageBox.Show(mErr.Message.ToString());
}
```

This image shows what I need.

[image]

Comment: give an example of that class and what you expect to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the VBScript equivalent of your C# code (only without error handling):

```
Const wbemFlagUseAmendedQualifiers = &H20000

strComputer = "."
Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set oClass = oWMI.Get("Win32_LogicalDisk", wbemFlagUseAmendedQualifiers)

strDesc = oClass.Qualifiers_("Description").Value
WScript.Echo strDesc
```