# How Do I Display the Descriptions for WMI Class Properties Using Vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I have been looking for a way to programmatically output the Description of a WMI class property, but cannot find out how to access the amended qualifier.

I have seen [this question on how to use VBScript to display WMI class descriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978919/get-the-description-from-an-wmi-class-using-vbscript), using the following snippet:

```
    Const wbemFlagUseAmendedQualifiers = &H20000

    Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set oClass = oWMI.Get("Win32_OperatingSystem", wbemFlagUseAmendedQualifiers)

    WScript.Echo oClass.Qualifiers_("Description").Value
```

The following image is what I want to extract, shown in WMI Code Creator:

[image]

Is there a method like this that could display the Description?

```
    Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set oProp = oWMI.Get("Win32_OperatingSystem.BootDevice", wbemFlagUseAmendedQualifiers)

    WScript.Echo oProp.Qualifiers_("Description").Value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Take your first example and insert `Properties_("BootDevice")` into the last line:

```
Const wbemFlagUseAmendedQualifiers = &H20000

Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set oClass = oWMI.Get("Win32_OperatingSystem", wbemFlagUseAmendedQualifiers)

WScript.Echo oClass.Properties_("BootDevice").Qualifiers_("Description").Value
```

Or if you need to loop through all class properties:

```
...
On Error Resume Next
For Each oProp in oClass.Properties_
  WScript.Echo oProp.Name & ": " & oProp.Qualifiers_("Description").Value
Next
```

Comment: Brilliant.  That makes perfect sense now that I see it.  Excellent, concise answer.  Thank you!